# Javascript Uncaught Type Error for Show More/ Less Button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up a truncate/ reveal button for long text. However the button is not working and the error message is "Error at line 15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'oneclick' of null."

line 15 is "button.onclick = function () {"

Full code is

```
<script>

var content = document.getElementById("content");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more");

 button.onclick = function () {

    if(content.className == "open"){
        //shrink the box
        content.className = "";
        button.innerHTML = "SHOW MORE";
    } else {
        //expand the box
        content.className = "open";
        button.innerHTML = "SHOW LESS";
    }

};
</script>


</head>
<body>


<div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ante dignissim, varius elit urna erat odio lectus. Aenean laoreet pellentesque justo maecenas nec, viverra diam cras, lorem at vitae vestibulum, arcu lobortis ac. Netus vitae wisi odio vitae sagittis tortor, cras mauris
<br>
<br>
Urna volutpat libero libero, sed aliquet habitant. Metus sed. Velit sodales mauris purus ac nullam, ac eget lectus quam odio quisque urna, sed tempor sodales lorem dolor velit vestibulum, dui mattis cursus consequat porttitor. Pede velit viverra magna consectetuer,  </div>

<a id="show-more">SHOW MORE</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){

    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var button = document.getElementById("show-more");

    button.onclick = function () {

        if(content.className == "open"){
            //shrink the box
            content.className = "";
            button.innerHTML = "SHOW MORE";
        } else {
            //expand the box
            content.className = "open";
            button.innerHTML = "SHOW LESS";
        }

    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: All you need is to add window.onload